# How to set custom object in body of message in cxf?

Tags: rest, cxf

I have a REST webservice with method custom (GET).

```
@GET
@Path("/custom")
public UIResponse custom(final UIParameters uiParameters){...}
```

As you can see this method has one argument. This is my custom object.

Object UIParameters is built from argument given as query string.

eg. http://example.com/custom?objectType=article

UIParameters object will contain one field:

```
UIParameters {
   String objectType = "article";
}
```

I have tried to use InInterceptor to get this parameter from URL, build UIParameter object and set Content of message. Unfortunatelly it doesn't work.
After that I've provide MessageBodyReader for UIParameters but it still doesn't work.

What should I do to achive this goal?

Thanks

Update:

In InInterceptor I've copied query string to http headers. Now part of URL where user place parameters is accessible in my MessageBodyReader. Here I can build my object UIParameters.

Everything works fine but I don't think that this solution is the best.

Does somebody know better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotation`QueryParam("")` allows to get all the query parameters injected.

You do not need an interceptor and it is not the recommended way. See CXF documentation http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-basics.html#JAX-RSBasics-Parameterbeans

```
@GET
@Path("/custom")
public UIResponse custom(@QueryParam("") UIParameters uiParameters)

class UIParameters {
      String objectType;
}
```

If you want to build the bean yourself using the query parameters use `@Context UriInfo` annotation

```
@GET
@Path("/custom")
public UIResponse custom( @Context UriInfo uriInfo){
     MultivaluedMap<String, String> params = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();
     new UIParameters().Builder()
        .objectType(params.getFirst("type"))
        .build();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Of course this is the best way but unfortunately I want to use builder pattern so I can't use setters.

Comment: Try without the setters. I copied them by custom, but seeing the documentation may not be necessary

Comment: How to invoke all the chain e.g. new UIParameters().Builder().objectType("type").build(); I want to validate whole object after setting all fields.

Comment: `@QueryParam` is managed by the JAX-RS implementation. This means that the object creation is perfomed before calling your method. If you want to build the bean yourself from query parameters use `@Context UriInfo` See updated answer

Comment: Thank you pedrofb. Your solutions are very helpful. This is great. I've used this approach in previous version of my app. Unfortuantelly I have to provide java client for consumers and I want to use common interface thus I can't use UriInfo class as argument.

Comment: I think you know all the available options to decide which solution is suitable for you. Reuse the java interface is a question of a different nature. I think you can ask a new specific questio n. Consider also to mark the answer as correct is solves your question or is helpful for you